# Garden spike light wiring

Tags: lighting

can someone tell me if the following looks right for connecting 10 garden spiked spot lights to a plug please? Thought I could run armoured cable from a plug to first Wiska box, then between the following boxes with the lights coming off each.

[image]

Comment: Are these AC mains voltage or DC low voltage? What kind of "armoured cable"? How are you going to get it under the sidewalk/path? What do the instructions say for running them in series? Without any of those details, the certainly _looks_ right, but there's no way of knowing if it's _actually_ right.

Comment: @FreeMan   You make a great comment. We need to know if they are line voltage or low voltage.  If LV hopefully all LED. If incandescent LV the OP really REALLY needs to account for voltage drop and use large gauge cable.   Given how the OP spelled   armoured  I'm guessing they are in the UK.  Here in my part of the planet (western US), armored cable is not considered suitable for direct burial. Also, line voltage runs have to be at least 18" below finished grade. The term armoured cable might have a different meaning, depending upon where they are on this planet. As always, local codes apply.

Comment: Thanks for the replies both! The lights I'm looking at are mains voltage: https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Products/GLGU10SPIKEBK.html?source=adwords&ad_position=&ad_id=415703895072&placement=&kw=&network=u&matchtype=&ad_type=&product_id=GLGU10SPIKEBK&product_partition_id=937379251562&campaign=shopping_lighting&version=finalurl_v3&gclid=CjwKCAiAm7OMBhAQEiwArvGi3HGtTDDEnYQ8OD3AabBXmDnX-eoNYMloKw26T8uGiELsFN1byFo86BoCHlwQAvD_BwE GU10 LED bulbs and yes, I'm in the UK. I can route the cable through a fence, so was thinking Tuf cable would be enough. Thanks

Comment: AC mains will kill you, so it has extremely strict rules for installing outdoor wiring.  Your approach there is nowhere near the mains requirements.   So you would be far, far better off doing that in low voltage wiring e.g. no higher than 24 volts.  The wiring rules are much relaxed, and are compatible with what you plan to do.

Comment: Be careful buying mail order, a lot of companies ship direct from China or a free-trade-zone warehouse like Amazon's... and those bypass the consumer safety schemes, allowing them to sell illegal and dangerous junk.  Safest to buy bricks and mortar, or websites of bricks and mortar firms (e.g. wickes.co.uk).  If it has the BSI kitemark, it's fine.